# assign opposite value in position of Integer vector in R

Tags: r

I have a large vector of integers measuring frequency of an event.
 Something like this

```
1
23
45
23
3
2
45
```

I want to reverse the numbers replacing each one with the opposite in the ordered list this way:

```
    1 becomes 45
    2 becomes 23
3 becomes 3
23 becomes 2...
```

And so on....
Take into account numbers are repeated.
A simple and elegant way apart from creating and merging two vectors of unique values inverted (the only I figured so far)?
Seeking for a mathematical approach

Expected output:

```
45
2
1
2
3
23
1
```

Comment: Not clear about the logic.  What would `3` become

Comment: 3. It&#39;s the &quot;central&quot; integer number from the list

Comment: Please sshow the full expected output as it is confusing

Comment: The process I figured: order unique values, invert, put side by side and assign. Nasty

Comment: Can you pleae update with your method as the replacement logic is not cleear to me

Comment: @akrun: I believe what is meant by OP is that there is a one-to-one mapping: 1 <-> 45, 2 <-> 23, since the subsequent 45 <-> 1 and 23 <-> 2 are already mapped, the following mapping is 3 <-> 3. The initial vector should be replaced by its mapped version.

Comment: @JorisChau  If you have a solution, please post it.  I don't have one

Comment: Added expected output

Answer (score 1):

OK. I think this is what you want. First, you have your original values

```
x <- c(1, 23, 45, 23, 3, 2, 45)
```

Then we get a sorted list of unique values

```
uniqx <- sort(unique(x))
```

Then, we can match each element in the list to one of those unique values with `match()`, and then replace it with a value from the reversed list of unique value.

```
rev(uniqx)[match(x, uniqx)]
# [1] 45  2  1  2  3 23  1
```

Comment: Yes. That is the "nasty" approach I mentioned before and the first that came to mind but hoping there's a mathematical approach instead the "match two lists side by side approach"